# Loading a model file as schema in mongoose/mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using this model from https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd :

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var TaskSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Kindly enter the name of the task'
  },
  Created_date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  status: {
    type: [{
      type: String,
      enum: ['pending', 'ongoing', 'completed']
    }],
    default: ['pending']
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tasks', TaskSchema);
```

On the last step 'putting everything together', it says i have to load the created model above. When I run the HTTP commands there has been no response to the server, and when I checked, there is no collection inside my database. How do I do that?

Comment: I think you should insert first a record in order to create your collections.

Comment: can you add the main code of your app, maybe something is wrong there

Answer (score 2):

That `required` in `name` has to be boolean or a function. You can use either:

```
required: true
```

or

```
required: [true, "Kindly enter the name of the task"]
```

Also you should check console to find out the exact problem which cause your application stopped.